# Flask / React / Nginx / Dockerfile - CORS issue

Tags: javascript, nginx, flask, axios

I am trying to use Nginx as a reverse proxy to deploy a Flask backend and a React.js frontend on Heroku with only one dyno. Everything works fine when I use flask and react.js built-in servers but I cannot make it properly works with Nginx, neither on local or Heroku.

Flask code

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
import time

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Flask app config + CORS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG = True

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

# accept CORS from frontend app
API_CORS_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8080",
]
CORS(app, origins=API_CORS_ORIGINS, supports_credentials=True)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# RESTFUL API
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
API_PREFIX = '/api'
api = Api(prefix=API_PREFIX)


class AuthenticationAPI(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'res': 'get'}, 200

    def post(self):
        print(request.get_json())
        return {'res': 'post'}, 200


class TimeAPI(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'res': time.time()}, 200


api.add_resource(AuthenticationAPI, '/auth')
api.add_resource(TimeAPI, '/time')

api.init_app(app)
```

Javascript code

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api'

const callBackendAuth = async () => await axios({
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    mode: 'cors',
    url: `${apiUrl}/auth`,
    data: {
        'username': 'user1',
        'password': 'pass1'
    }
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
});

const callBackendTime = async () => axios({
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    mode: 'cors',
    url: `${apiUrl}/time`
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
})
```

Nginx configuration

```
server {
  listen 80; # $PORT;

  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Serve the static files
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  # https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/#static-file-caching
  location /static {
    expires    1y;
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
  }

  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Allow access to backend using Nginx as reverse proxy
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  location /api {
    include             proxy_params;
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_redirect      default;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the Nginx proxy is not passing response headers from the JavaScript app to the client. You either need to set those headers in he Nginx config with `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://url";` or specify the header with `proxy_pass_header`

Comment: Didn't change anything in the final results but thanks for the advice, I added ```proxy_pass_header```.

Comment: If you open the JavaScript application in your browser you can verify if the header is there by opening the developer tools

Comment: The problem isn't from the JavaScript application, I investigated further and I asked a more precise question if you have the same problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63206239/using-gunicorn-with-ubuntulatest-docker-image.